# pass js variables to php variables on another page and go to target page

Tags: php, jquery

I need to pass some js variables from `index.php` to php variable on `tags.php`
- without using forms
- without using address bar
- and go to `tags.php`

**index.php**

```
$('#m1tags').click(function(){
var id = $('.pmarked').data('id'); // an integer
$.ajax({
    url: 'tags.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'id': id},
    success: function() {

    }
});
location.href='tags.php';
});
```

**tags.php**

```
<?php echo $_POST['id'];?>
```

`Notice: Undefined idex: id...`

Any help?

Comment: you need to send a form instead of an ajax call! Right now you send everything to tags.php, but then "refresh" tags.php without the passed vars.

Comment: this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript post request like a form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request you made is asynchronous which means that it's happening in the background and then the script continues to execute on the same page. You are sending a POST request and then redirecting user using a different request.

You can send a hidden form using JavaScript so the user will be redirected there along with POST data in the same request.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var id = 60;
    $("#id-input").val(id);
    $("#tags-form").submit();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="tags-form" method="POST" action="tags.php">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id-input">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to make "tag.php" get infos from an unknown source.
To send info to a php page you need to use a form or a url variables.

Even when you use ajax url variables and post variables are used (when a user's related infos are needed).